# Error when using MSP430 driver library: "Only large data model supported for this ROM."

Tags: compiler-errors, msp430

I'm relatively new to MSP430-programming and want to use the driver lib (https://www.ti.com/tool/MSPDRIVERLIB) for the MSP430FR2355. I included the library `"driverlib.h"` in an new empty project with the following code:

```
#include <msp430.h>
#include "driverlib.h"


/**
 * main.c
 */
int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // stop watchdog timer
    
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately when compiling I get the following error message:

`"{path}\TestLaunchPad\driverlib\MSP430FR2xx_4xx\rom_headers/rom_driverlib_fr235x.h", line 39: fatal error #35: #error directive: "Only large data model supported for this ROM."`, where `{path}` is the location of the project on my computer.

The affected part in the file `rom_driverlib_fr235x.h` of the library is the following:

```
#if (defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) && !defined(__LARGE_DATA_MODEL__)) || \
(defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__) && (__DATA_MODEL__!=__DATA_MODEL_LARGE__))
#error "Only large data model supported for this ROM."
#endif
```

I don't understand, what I am doing wrong or how I could specify the large data model, respectively.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer on another forum. Maybe someone else faces the same problem, so I'll post the solution here:

In Code Composer Studio go to **Properties -> Processor Options** and try the settings as shown in
[this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfKXn.png).

Many thanks to Johnson, who provided this answer (https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp-low-power-microcontrollers-group/msp430/f/msp-low-power-microcontroller-forum/1001359/mspdriverlib-error-when-using-msp430-driver-library-only-large-data-model-supported-for-this-rom)!

Best regards.